# Dictionary Instance Override

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
public class Turf : Atom
{
    public Dictionary<Type, int> allowed_contents = new Dictionary<Type, int>()
    {
    };

public class Plains : Turf
{
    public new Dictionary<Type, int> allowed_contents = new Dictionary<Type, int>()
    {
        {typeof(Forest), 100},
        {typeof(Tall_Grass),  25},
        {typeof(Mountain), 10}
    };
```

How would I go about actually overriding the allowed_contents? I did read up on this, and found an answer with getters, but it involved creating multiple Dictionaries per one object, which is not something I would like.

Comment: Why "override" this at all?  Why not just have your `Plains` constructor set the `allowed_contents` data?  `allowed_contents` is a field anyway so you aren't even preventing anything outside from modifying it

Comment: That is a possibility I didn't consider thinking it would be unreadable, but that is a valid option, I guess.

The question still stands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to override anything. You can just create a new dictionary in your constructor:

```
public class Plains : Turf
{
    public Plains()
    {
        allowed_contents = new Dictionary<Type, int>()
        {
            {typeof(Forest), 100},
            {typeof(Tall_Grass),  25},
            {typeof(Mountain), 10}
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that any consumer of your class can create a new Dictionary as well.  The better way to do this would be to make the Dictionary field private, and expose it as a property with a public getter (to allow anyone to add/read/delete/ from it) and a protected setter.